Unusual disk space occupied by wsl (ubuntu 20) in windows 11 system
I have installed WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) on my Windows 11 system with a 1TB SSD. After working with the WSL setup for a couple of weeks, I've noticed that WSL occupies almost 620GB of disk space, whereas the home folder inside WSL occupies around 270GB, which is understandable. I'm unsure how Ubuntu is occupying the additional ~350GB on the disk. I have tried to examine the WSL folders one by one but haven't found any questionable folders that could explain this unexpected usage, except for the /mnt/wslg folder, which is 210GB in size. I have attached a picture of the /mnt/wslg folder below.
Is it okay to delete this folder, and if I do, will it affect the home folder? Additionally, I would like to know any other tips to clear out this ghost space occupation on the disk. When I delete something, is it stored somewhere equivalent to the Windows Recycle Bin, or is it a permanent delete (like Shift+Delete) in WSL?
There are too many questions, but I appreciate your time. Thanks!

